# XCode 5 doesn't break in C++ templates

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, templates

I have an XCode static library included in my iOS project. It has a number of template header files. If I set a breakpoint in any of the members of the template classes, they don't fire. But, I found a workaround. If I put an `assert(false)` in my code and run it, the debugger will break. Then I can set the breakpoint in the file and remove the `assert(false)`. This breakpoint will work fine. If I make any edits to this file they do not show up in my "actual" source files. It's like xcode has duplicates of my template headers and will only allow me to set breakpoints there. I can only get access to these "duplicates" if I can force the debugger to break there.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on? This is a recent problem, I never had issues setting breakpoints in C++ template headers before.

Comment: You didn't happen to hit Command+Y (Disable breakpoints) perhaps?

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the problem. That reminds me I forgot to mention something important though. I have breakpoints set in objective-c++ source files in the parent project and those work.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that the breakpoint on the template class is enabled as well.

[image]